# Setting jQuery Cookie on collapse/expand menu (complicated)

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

I'm trying to add jquery .cookies to my existing collapse/expand menu but for the life of me I can't see where I fail horribly.

Can anyone help me figure this issue out? I've been looking at code for a little under 9 hours now and this is the last piece I was supposed to write today. I fear that my brain has literally reached it's limit but I can't stand leaving the work unfinished. It's probably something easy and I just can't see it.

I've set the cookie as visible_state and what's supposed to happen, is every time a user clicks to expand/collapse/toggle an area of the menu, it stores the cookie as a class.

**Edit** : I forgot to mention...
cexpand = the cookie class for expanded...

ccollapse - the cookie class for collapsed

My original .js (working menu)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
  // Grow/Shrink
  $('#menu3 > li > a.expanded + ul').show('blind');
  $('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed + ul').hide('blind');
  $('#menu3 > li > a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').parent().find('> ul').toggle('blind');
});
$('.expand_all').click(function() {
$('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed').addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').parent().find('> ul').show('blind');
});
$('.collapse_all').click(function() {
$('#menu3 > li > a.expanded').addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').parent().find('> ul').hide('blind');
});
}, 0);
});
```

My new .js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var visible_state = $.cookie("visible_state");
setTimeout(function() {
if ($('.expanded').attr('class')=='cexpand'){
  $(this).removeClass('cexpand');
  $(this).addClass('ccollapse');
  $.cookie('visible_state', 'ccollapse', { path: '/', expires: 100});
  $(this).hide('blind');
} else if ($('.collapsed').attr('class')=='ccollapse'){
  $(this).removeClass('ccollapse');
  $(this).addClass('cexpand');
  $.cookie('visible_state', 'cexpand', { path: '/', expires: 100 });
  $(this).show('blind');        
}   
  $('#menu3 > li > a.expanded + ul').show('blind');
  $('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed + ul').hide('blind');    
  $('#menu3 > li > a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded', 'cexpand').toggleClass('collapsed', 'ccollapse').parent().find('> ul').toggle('blind');
});

$('.expand_all').click(function() {
  $('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed').addClass('expanded', 'cexpand').removeClass('collapsed', 'ccollapse').parent().find('> ul').show('blind');
});
$('.collapse_all').click(function() {
  $('#menu3 > li > a.expanded').addClass('collapsed', 'ccollapse').removeClass('expanded', 'cexpand').parent().find('> ul').hide('blind');
});
}, 0);
});
```

****EDIT** **close.js****

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

var visible_state = $.cookie('visible_state');

 if (visible_state == null){
$('#menu3 > li > a').addClass('collapsed');
$('#menu3 > li > a + ul.1').addClass('expanded');

 };

 if (visible_state == 'collapsed'){
$('#menu3 > li > a').removeClass('expanded');
$('#menu3 > li > a').addClass('collapsed');

$.cookie('visible_state', 'collapsed', { path: '/', expires: 100 });
 };
  if (visible_state == 'expanded'){
$('#menu3 > li > a').addClass('expanded');
$.cookie('visible_state', 'expanded', { path: '/', expires: 100 });
 };

 $('#menu3 > li > a').click(function() {
 if ($('#menu3 > li > a').attr('class')=='expanded'){
$(this).removeClass('expanded');
$(this).addClass('collapsed');
$.cookie('visible_state', 'collapsed', { path: '/', expires: 100 });

} else{
$(this).removeClass('collapsed');
$(this).addClass('expanded');
$.cookie('visible_state', 'expanded', { path: '/', expires: 100 });

}
});

$('#menu3 > li > a.expanded + ul.1').show('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.expanded + ul.2').show('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.expanded + ul.3').show('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.expanded + ul.4').show('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.expanded + ul.5').show('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed + ul.1').hide('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed + ul.2').hide('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed + ul.3').hide('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed + ul.4').hide('blind');
$('#menu3 > li > a.collapsed + ul.5').hide('blind');

$('.expand_all').click(function() {
  $('#menu3 > li >           a.collapsed').addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').parent().find('>   ul').show('blind');
  $.removeCookie('visible_state');
  $.cookie('visible_state', 'expanded', { path: '/', expires: 100 });
});
$('.collapse_all').click(function() {
  $('#menu3 > li >   a.expanded').addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').parent().find('> ul').hide('blind');
  $.removeCookie('visible_state');
  $.cookie('visible_state', 'collapsed', { path: '/', expires: 100 });
});
});
```

My .html

```
<div id="leftnav" style="clear:left;">
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="menu3" class="leftnavmenu">
    <li class="leftnavitem1"><a href="#" class="expanded">Category 1 <span>1</span>   </a>
      <ul>
    <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Link 1 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Link 2 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Link 3 <span>1</span></a></li>
      </ul
    </li>
    <li class="leftnavitem2"><a href="#" class="expanded">Category 2 <span>1</span></a>
      <ul>
    <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Link 1 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Link 2 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Link 3 <span>1</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
        <li class="leftnavitem3"><a href="#" class="collapsed">Category 3 <span>1</span></a>
      <ul>
    <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Link 1 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Link 2 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Link 3 <span>1</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="leftnavitem4"><a href="#" class="collapsed">Category 4  <span>1</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Link 1 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Link 2 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Link 3 <span>1</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="leftnavitem5"><a href="#" class="collapsed">Category 5 <span>1</span></a>
      <ul>
            <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Link 1 <span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Link 2 <span>1</span></a></li>
        <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Link 3 <span>1</span></a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I will mentally buy a coffee? for anyone who puts an end to my misery.

Comment: Original: http://jsfiddle.net/DXSVD/ New: http://jsfiddle.net/4nmph/. There is an error which you really should have posted in your question: `Uncaught TypeError: Object ... has no method 'cookie'`. Do not just stare a code, look up the error message in Chrome's developer tools for Firefox's FireBug.

Comment: I've looked over you code in some more detail now. I find it odd that whenever you access a cookie, you always refer to same name and do not store any additional detail on which menu it is that is visible on which. It seems like you are just setting one global flag for them all, which I find very odd. I will provide an answer tomorrow that will involve rewriting pretty much all of your code as I can see other structural problems too.

Answer (score 0):

`$.cookie` doesn't exist. Which plugin are you using?

Otherwise I would suggest using [Amplify JS Store](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/). Cookies are not the best way of storing things in the era of Html 5.

Comment: I was attempting to use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie - I edited my original and added the newest code that I have now. It still doesn't work, but at least the cookies are trying to work. I've not used jquery that much so don't expect too much out of me. The Amplify JS Store looks great. I'm going to try to use it instead, although I'm in the same boat again with not knowing how to implement it in my existing menu's .js

Comment: Ahh! I am so close....

This is what I have now, it's almost working correctly... if anyone can spot where I'm going wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

I've edited original post with my newest .js labeled "close.js"